# Vertically wobbly figure in Beamer over slides

Tags: beamer, floats, vertical-alignment

I have successive slides where one column is text and the other column is just an image. The image stays the same, so I simply kept the exact same code in a new frame. However, at my surprise, when I vary the text of the left column, the vertical alignment of the picture in the right column changes. I would like the picture to stay still from a frame to another.

Here is a MWE which should make it clearer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

Sample text

\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}

\centering
\def\svgwidth{\textwidth}
\input{fig.pdf_tex}
\caption{Wobbly figure}

\end{figure}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

A much longer sample text which messes up with the vertical alignment of the image in the other column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}

\centering
\def\svgwidth{\textwidth}
\input{fig.pdf_tex}
\caption{Wobbly figure}

\end{figure}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `\begin{colummns}[T]`?

Comment: I just tried but it does not work on my side. Does it work in general?

Comment: It aligns both columns at the top. All you need to do is to move the figure a bit down if you don't want it at the top.

Comment: Well, that is what I thought, T for top like for figures, but for a reason it does not seem to align the figure and the text to the top. Does it work for you?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you cannot squeeze two columns of `.5\textwidth` besides each other, this leaves no room for the intercolumn space. Either make them a bit smaller (e.g. `.48\textwidth`) or use `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]`

Comment: You also don't need `\centering` in your figure, figures are centred by default in beamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. Of course, one has to make the usual corrections and I do not have your figure.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}

Sample text

\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{figure}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Wobbly figure}

\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}

A much longer sample text which messes up with the vertical alignment of the image in the other column. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.485\textwidth}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{figure}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Wobbly figure}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works now! I was not aware of the usual changes I guess, I had just put `[T]` after the `columns` beginning.